# Dynamic model in LinkTo component in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-octane, glimmer.js

I am using Ember 3.18, I am facing the below issue. Consider the following routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('author');
  this.route('author' , {path:"/author/:author_id"});
});
```

Now, in my hbs file, I am trying to transition to the above routes using a single LinkTo. As you can see, only the second route requires model attribute. In simple terms, I want to **combine** the below 2 into a single line.

```
<LinkTo @route="author" />
<LinkTo @route="author" @model="2" />
```

As you can see, I require the model attribute to be gone in certain cases and availble in certain cases.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way forward is to tweak your routing setup a bit. I know you want to *combine* the routes, but it's hard/confusing, imo, and would be "more standard" to do something more traditional like:

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('author', function() {
    this.route('view', {path:":author_id"});
  });
});
```

and

```
<LinkTo @route="author.index" />
<LinkTo @route="author.view" @model="2" />
```

`author.index` would match `/author`
and `author.view` (with a `@model`) would match `/author/2`.

Note that index is an implicit convention of the web, and not needed in the router.js file

Comment: I understand that tweaking the routing setup helps here. But, I am still curious about combining the two into a single line. Like by using the `let` helper and based on some condition, include the model otherwise remove it. Is it possible?

Comment: maybe if your plain route was `author*`, but it _feels like_, an attempt to trick the route pattern matcher